# How to move up to the ending parenthesis of the enclosing list (if it exists)?

Tags: motion, paredit

In paredit mode, `C-M-u` (`paredit-backward-up`) is used to move the point

> backward up out of the enclosing list

The point is parked at the beginning parenthesis of the enclosing list. My question is:

*How to move up one level of sexp similarly but have the point parked at the ending parenthesis instead (if an enclosing parenthesis exists)?*

I am asking is that sexp evaluation with `C-x C-e` (`eval-last-sexp`) happens at the ending parenthesis (instead of the beginning). And I'd like to repeatedly jump up to a position where I can evaluate using `C-x C-e` immediately. Ideally, I'd like to have a function that repeatedly jump out and stop at the top-level, where there is no enclosing parenthesis. e.g., given:

```
'(((how) are) ((you) (do|ing so)) far)
```

I'd like to move the cursor *quickly* to the ending parenthesis (I mean with one possibly repeated key combination, as I need to do this a lot).

```
'(((how) are) ((you) (doing so)) far)|
```

**-- Update --**

I needed more specif control of navigation than the `end-of-defun` suggested in the comments.

Below was a larger example I tested in a scheme-mode buffer, with point indicated by `|`:

```
(car '(a b c))
'xyz
'(((how) are) ((you) (do|ing so)) far)
'(atom turkey) 'or
(car '(a b c))
```

I tried `C-M-x` before at the above position, and it gives me

> => a

, which is not the sexp I am trying to evaluate.

Hitting C-M-e (end-of-defun) followed by C-x C-e produces the same result.

Comment: You can press C-M-e (`end-of-defun`) followed by C-x C-e, or press C-M-x without moving the cursor.

Comment: @jagrg Thanks. I just added some updates about C-M-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Paredit, `M-x up-list` but it is not bound by default. You can also use `C-M-u` then `C-M-f`, but that's not a repeatable binding.

With Paredit, `M-x paredit-forward-up` is available on `C-M-n`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this ...

```lisp
(defalias 'eval-next-sexp
  (kbd "C-M-f C-x C-e C-M-b"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-y") 'eval-next-sexp)
```

What I have done is created a keyboard macro, named it, inserted it, and bound it to a custom key.

Since you are trying to learn elisp, I hope you will be able to fill in the gaps in my response.

Btw, if it is not clear to you, you need to keep doing `C-M-u` until you reach the sexp you want, and then do `C-x C-y` (which you have defined here).  See [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

---

I don't use `paredit`, and I am not sure if it re-defines vanilla `C-M-u`.

I know for a fact that `smartparens` redefines `C-M-u` in a manner that I don't like.  So, I have disabled the overriding behaviour of `C-M-u`.

Remember, when people say `C-M-u`, it is the `backward-up-list` defined by vanilla Emacs, and NOT the `C-M-u` that paredit sets it to.

If `paredit`'s`C-M-u` leaves you in the "global" scope, then disable that behaviour.