# How to ignore errors in the middle of a key/command sequence?

Tags: motion, paredit

I wanted to jump to the end of the current top-level S-expression as described in this question: [How to move up to the ending parenthesis of the enclosing list (if it exists)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73585). The goal is to position the point in a location such that the current `top-level` S-expression can be evaluated with `C-x C-e` (and then evaluate it). Based on the answers linked above, I have the following shortcut key sequence:

```
(defalias 'eval-next-sexp
  ;; (kbd "M-m C-f C-u C-M-n C-x C-e")
  (kbd "M-m C-f C-u C-M-n")
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-y") 'eval-next-sexp)
```

As I am using paredit mode, `M-m` moves the cursor to the first non-whitespace position, `C-f` moves one letter into the S-expression, `C-u C-M-n` repeatedly moves up the hierarchy of parentheses (`paredit-forward-up`) until it cannot move any further.

So far this has been (mostly) successful in moving the point to where it needs to be, and a subsequent `C-x C-e` evaluates the expression.

The problem is that when I tried to combine the move and the evaluation, as shown in the commented line: `(kbd "M-m C-f C-u C-M-n C-x C-e")`, the evaluation doesn't happen because the movement command generates an error when stopping:

> After 0 kbd macro iterations: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses",
> 1647, 12558

My guess is that `C-u C-M-n` reached top and generates an error.

The question is:

*How can errors from previous commands as above be ignored and the subsequent key strokes be executed?*

*Additionally, is it possible to repeat a key combination/command (`C-M-n` here) until an error happens?* (If so, the going up can be implemented more reliably)

Comment: Given your last question, you probably realize that this is not sufficient if you start deeper than a nesting level of 4. I don't know how to repeat until you get the error, but using a `C-u C-u` prefix will suffice for 16 levels which is probably more than enough in practice - but you can use three of them for 64 levels if necessary - that should be enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: Why is the initial `M-m C-f` necessary?

Comment: @NickD Thanks. The `M-m C-f` is just a heuristic to get into the top-level sexp. e.g.  in `|(add1 1)`. `C-M-n` will do nothing. After the initial move, `(|add1 1)`, `C-M-n` works. Maybe there are better ways..

Comment: Also, I misunderstood the `C-u` and thought it's the same as a while loop.

Comment: It's a [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to ignore errors in a keyboard macro, but you can certainly write a function that ignores the error:

```el
(defun ndk/paredit-move-to-end-of-top-level ()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (paredit-forward-up 1000)
    (error nil)))
```

`paredit-forward-up` is the command that is bound to `C-M-n`. This tries to go up 1000 levels, catches the error and returns nil. If 1000 levels are not enough, you can wrap the call in a `while` like this: `(while t (paredit-forward-up 1000)` - that will repeat infinitely, until it gets the error of course.

You can bind the function to a key (that's why the `(interactive)` form is there):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c z") #'ndk/paredit-move-to-end-of-top-level)
```

and define a macro that does `(kbd "C-c z C-x C-e")`.

N.B. I've left out the `M-m C-f` heuristic, but you can put it back if you want.

EDIT: to answer your comment, you can call `eval-last-sexp` in the function but it takes an argument - the error message is telling you that you called it with 0 arguments but it requires 1 argument - read the doc string with `C-h f eval-last-sexp` to see that, but it is surprisingly unenlightening and a bit stingy in the descripiton of what values the argument can take: making the argument `nil` is probably the best in order to avoid output in the buffer itself (`nil` makes the output appear in the echo area). In any case, here's how to do it:

```el
(defun ndk/paredit-move-to-end-of-top-level-eval ()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (paredit-forward-up 1000)
    (error nil))
  (eval-last-sexp nil))
```

Comment: I also tried to add `(eval-last-sexp)`  in the end of the function, but it  gives an error `paredit-move-to-end-of-top-level: Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 0`